# Looking for a switch or circuit that resets when power is lost in a 12V application?

Tags: power-supply

I'm trying to configure an A/C compressor command circuit that will lose power to the switch when the power is turned off and stay de-energized when power is turned back on. Requiring the switch to be turned off before turning back on. I have seen a few similar questions asked and answered on this function for similar needs but I'm either by way of hunger or inadequate rest, unable to adapt to my specific needs. Would someone be able to help me figure this out?

Rundown: The body control module the controls the HVAC functions of the truck has malfunctioned and no longer sends power out to the AC compressor nor is commanding or controlling the circuit to cycle the system in run function. I have independent control of blower fan and AC compressor operation. I have currently created a circuit with a toggle switch controlled ground circuit through pressure switches to cycle the compressor. I want to prevent the operator from being able to leave the switch on and have it energizing the compressor coil when the truck is in a key on/engine off state. For this I figure a resetting circuit would be required, but can't visualize in my head how to make that happen.

Comment: I barely skimmed your writing. But from what I got out of it, I'd imagine using a relay, then. They will drop out and stay that way when power is lost and then returned. Use one of the switch poles to power the relay, bypassed also by a manual, momentary PB switch. I think I'd need more details, though, to offer better thoughts.

Comment: It needs to be as simple as possible and not requiring a driver of a truck to remove both hands from the steering wheel and crossing arms across themselves to operate.

Comment: Davide is describing what I was thinking. As far as "both hands" and other safety issues, there isn't enough detail for me to know. I think it should be fine and useful. But you'd have to be the one to work out the details so that's true in your case. If you provided mechanical layout details and other bits, I suppose I could offer more. But I'm ignorant of your situation and you are the expert. All I can say is that a relay is the usual answer for something like this and that I'm almost certain you can make it work very well. But you are the one on-scene. So that bit is in your lap.

Comment: A single pushbutton is as simple as it gets, and that's what the answers are giving you

Answer (score 6):

To illustrate David Andrea's answer, using a relay with a 12V DC coil, and two poles (switches):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDLCSl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When SW1 is pressed, the relay coil is energised. When it's released, the coil remains energised because the the first pair of relay contacts (which are in parallel with SW1) are still closed. This condition will persist until 12V power is interrupted, at which point the relay switches off again. It will then stay off, even after power returns, and you will need to press SW1 again to resume the cycle.

The second pair of relay contacts is free to control whatever you like.

The diode is there to protect the relay contacts and SW1 from coil back-EMF, do not omit that.

Answer (score 4):

Use a relay with two sets of contacts, one for the load, one of its own coil.

1. Press a momentary switch to engage the relay.
2. The relay comes on, powers itself and the load

When power goes away, the relay disengages.

Answer (score 2):

An electromagnetic relay would be required.

Here's the schematic.

[image]

An 'engine running' contact, if available, would be the right replacement for 'ignition on'.

Comment: In cars and light vans I've worked on, I've taken the engine running signal from the feed to the back of the radio

Comment: The D+ terminal came in handy, for the purpose, with older Bosch alternators.